# Only one css media query affects element's style (only happens with Chrome, not Firefox)

Tags: css, media-queries

I cannot figure out why only one of these two media queries works.

This is my code

```
/* Desktop screen code ... */

/* media queries start */

@media (min-width: 751px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .element {
        background-color: red;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
    .element {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
```

Only the first query (i.e. for width between 751px and 1024px) works, and I get the same result even if I swap the order of the queries or comment out the first one (in this latter case the second query simply does affect the element).

This is getting a bit frustrating and I am pretty sure this must be due to me not seeing a pretty obvious error, so I'm ready (and happy) to be enlightened here.

Edit 2: After additional testing I realized that the problem is present only on chrome (v70.0.3538.77) and not on firefox (v 63.0), running on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: This appears to work just fine when I tested it using Codepen and Chrome's Dev tools :)

Comment: Just an idiot thought, but what's your screen resolution? If the 2nd one wont work, change `max-width: 750px` to `max-width: 7500px` just to try it out.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to close your first rule

```
@media (min-width: 751px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .element {
        background-color: red;
    }
}  <----- This was missing

@media (max-width: 750px) {
    .element {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
```

```css
@media (min-width: 751px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .element {
    background-color: red;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
  .element {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  Test
</div>
```

Comment: You are right but unfortunately I did not make that mistake original code. I got the syntax wrong when writing the post but not in the css.

Comment: @Fede9390 The fixed code is working. You might have a different rule that overrides it. Please add the code that doesn't work, otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: Edit 2: After additional testing I realized that the problem is present only on chrome (v70.0.3538.77) and not on firefox (v 63.0), running on Ubuntu 16.04. (updated my question accordingly)

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed the first media query. Check syntax 5 times before wasting time on stack :D

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing both of the queries to

```
   @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 751px) {
    .element {
        background-color: red;
    }

@media only screen and  (max-width: 750px) {
    .element {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue in two different ways:

1) use `min-device-width` instead of `min-width`. However this meant that the media queries would not fire when I resized the browser's window on a computer

2) instert the tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in the `<head>` of the html file. With this, everything works both on chrome and firefox